# CloudFileShare CreateIfNotExistsAsync().Wait method throwing The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request

Tags: azure-storage, aggregateexception

I am trying to use the Azure File Service preview as a mapped drive between my two instances of a cloud service and I came across the following blog post with some details:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsazurestorage/archive/2014/05/12/introducing-microsoft-azure-file-service.aspx?CommentPosted=true#commentmessage

I have signed up for the preview version of the storage account and created a new storage account and verified that the file endpoint is included. I then use the following code to attempt to create the share programmatically:

```
CloudStorageAccount account = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SecondaryStorageConnectionString"].ToString());
CloudFileClient client = account.CreateCloudFileClient();
CloudFileShare share = client.GetShareReference("SCORM");
try
{
  share.CreateIfNotExistsAsync().Wait();
}
catch (AggregateException e)
{
  var test = e.Message;
  var test1 = e.InnerException.Message;
}
```

On the CreateIfNotExistsAsync().Wait() method I am getting a Aggregate exception and when I look at the Inner details it just says The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request.

Comment: The error was caused due to the "SCORM" reference in the variable, the Azure File Services shares must contain only lowercase letters or else this will happen, got some better errors while running cmdlets using the "SCORM" name in PS3

Answer (score 1):

Your comment is the correct answer. Please refer to [Naming and Referencing Shares, Directories, Files, and Metadata](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn167011.aspx) article for more information.